# Best mysql db design to solve timezone issues

Tags: mysql, database-design

I faced problem with timezone on my last two projects. So What is best way to sort out problems with timezone on db design.

I mean, What format should i added date time stamp.

On of my problem. My client asked me to expire particular event on users timezone. How can i solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, the simplest thing I could think of would be to store three values:

- UTC (DATETIME),
- timezone offset for datetime in minutes (SMALLINT) (-1440 to 1440)
- DST (daylight saving time), 0 or 1 (TINYINT)

I originally was thinking of timezone offset in hours. @yercube reminded me of other places with 15 min or 30 min additional offsets . For example, these cities have these times:

- New York City at 4:00 PM
- Bangalore 1:30 AM next day
- Katmandhu 1:45 AM next day

You would have to

- perform date arithmetic to handle display of datetimes
- compare datetimes as pure UTC values

Comment: Will the offset (TINYINT) store hours or minutes? The timezone offset can be half an hour or 15 minutes.

Comment: @ypercube Sorry, I was thinking in hours. You are right because Bangalore, India is on 1:24 AM right now (3:54 in NYC). So make timezone offset in minutes. I'll adjust my answer.